# Is this a “good enough” statement of Wigner's theorem from Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, symmetry

I [posted this on math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3029130/166791) and got no replies, so I'm trying my luck here!

I'm a fourth year physics and math student who is writing up a report on some quantum mechanical symmetries and their consequences. The "audience" for my paper are either senior physics majors or first year graduate students in physics. [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem)'s mathematical content is unfortunately beyond the scope of my report so I decided to "water it down". My question is this: is this an acceptably simplified version of Wigner's theorem?

**Theorem** (Wigner)
 Let $\Psi, \Phi$ be arbitrary state vectors in a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Suppose $\delta: \mathscr{H} \mapsto \mathscr{H}$ is bijective and Wigner symmetric (that is, under the mapping $\delta$, the transition probability $\langle \Psi | \Phi \rangle$ is unchanged). Then

1. there exists a linear and unitary or antilinear and antiunitary operator $U$ such that
       $$\delta(\psi) = U \psi U^{-1},$$
2. $U$ is unique up to an arbitrary phase factor.

Is there anything I'm misunderstanding with this formulation of Wigner's theorem?

Answer (score 3):

$\let\d=\delta \def\sH{\mathscr H}$
Some amendments are needed.

1) This is merely notational. Don't write $\d:\sH\mapsto\sH$ but
rather $\d:\sH\to\sH$. "$\to$" is used between domain and codomain of a
map. "$\mapsto$" between a point in domain and its image in codomain.
Example: $$f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb R,\quad z \mapsto f(z) = |z|^2.$$

2) Transition probability is $|\langle\Psi|\Phi\rangle|^2$. This is
the right definition ot transition probability in QM. The difference is
also fundamental for the meaning of theorem, as conservation of
$\langle\Psi|\Phi\rangle$ is much stronger and is essentially the
theorem's thesis.

3) Unitary and antiunitary imply linear and antilinear respectively.
So those clauses could and should be suppressed.

4) Not $\d(\psi) = U \psi U^{-1}$, but $\d(\Psi) = U \Psi$ (note
capitals).

Comment: In addition to Elio's remarks, I stress that the hypotheses of Wigner theorem demand that $\delta$ tranforms rays into rays bijectively, not vectors into vectors.

Comment: @Valter Moretti Hi Valter! You're right. In my excuse I tried to
adhere to OP's request: *is this an acceptably simplified version of
Wigner's theorem?* And decided to leave rays apart. Of course it
remains to be seen if this is an "acceptably simplified version".

Comment: Hi Elio. Barring the issue of the rays, it is acceptable, I think. One other minor remark it is that the nature unitary or antiunitary of $U$ is decided by $\delta$ unless $\dim H =1$ where both cases are admitted for the same $\delta$.